# Storing .well-known/assetlinks.json in public repo?

Tags: android, security

Is it safe to store the file `.well-known/assetlinks.json` in a public repo? Since the statement list asks for a signing key, it seems like this is a sensitive file?

Comment: I mean, it _is_ called `.well-known`, not `.keep-secret` soooo....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google's [official generator](https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator) does not ask for a signing key, just the fingerprint of the associated app. If some tool is asking for the signing key you might have encountered a phishing attempt.

Comment: Ah, of course. I'm using Android Studio, but I guess I didn't read the explanation very carefully. It says, "Specify either the signing config or the keystore file used to sign your app **to obtain the SHA256 fingerprint**."

Comment: That is fine, the fingerprint simply confirms the app is signed by your key. The fingerprint is not a secret itself.